# Making a button unclickable until jQuery .load() has finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm currently using the following code for my read more buttons:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.more-link").attr("href", "");
  $("a.more-link").attr("onclick", "return false;");  
      
  $('.readmore').each(function(index) {
    var $link = $(this);
    $(".readmore").prependTo('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #bottominfo');
  });
      
  $('.readmore').click(function() {  
    var $link = $(this);
    if ( $link.attr("alt") == "read more" ) {
      $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').load($link.attr("title") + ' #mainarticle', function(index) {
            $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').hide();  
            $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').slideToggle('slow');
          });
       
      $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').attr("class", $link.attr("id"));
       
      $link.attr('alt','read less');      
    } else {
      $('#'+ $link.attr("id") + ' > .' + $link.attr("id")).hide();
      $link.attr('alt','read more'); 
    }
    return false;
 });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that if the user double clicks (or more) on the button it calls the function multiple times.

How do I make the button non-clickable until the `.load()` have finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to add a loading class to the link. I have also just done a quick clean up on your code. I didn't look into how it works but i'm sure if you spend a bit more time you can make it a lot more efficient

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.more-link").attr("href", "")
                  .attr("onclick", "return false;");  

  $('.readmore').each(function(index) {
    var $link = $(this);
    //wouldn't this call all the elements with "readmore" class????
    $(".readmore").prependTo('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #bottominfo');
  });

  $('.readmore').click(function() {
    var $link = $(this);

    //check if it has already been clicked
    if($link.hasClass("loading")) return false;
    //add the loading class
    $link.addClass("loading");


    if ( $link.attr("alt") == "read more" ) {
      $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').load($link.attr("title") + ' #mainarticle', function(index) {
            $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').hide()
                                                         .slideToggle('slow');

            //it's done now and we can remove the loading class so we can click it again
            $link.removeClass("loading");

          }).attr("class", $link.attr("id"));

      $link.attr('alt','read less');      
    } else {
      $('#'+ $link.attr("id") + ' > .' + $link.attr("id")).hide();
      $link.attr('alt','read more');

      //add it here as well
      $link.removeClass("loading");
    }
    return false;
 });
});
```

**Tips:** I notice you call the same selectors multiple times. Always check the [api doc](http://api.jquery.com/) and see what the methods you are calling do return. Most of them do return the element back, so then you can call the next method without `$()`

Example: `$("div").hide().slideToggle('slow');`

Comment: Sometimes it loads nicely, and other times it seems to be jerky and completely reset the page.

Comment: to test it, add alert() after $link.addClass("loading"); you will see one alert message even if you double click before the content has been loaded

Comment: No problem at all! I don't know if this is the best method but I usually do this if I want a quick block

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just run the function on .load instead?

```
$(document).load(function() {
  $("a.more-link").attr("href", "");
  $("a.more-link").attr("onclick", "return false;");  

  $('.readmore').each(function(index) {
    var $link = $(this);
    $(".readmore").prependTo('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #bottominfo');
  });

  $('.readmore').click(function() {  
    var $link = $(this);
    if ( $link.attr("alt") == "read more" ) {
      $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').load($link.attr("title") + ' #mainarticle', function(index) {
            $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').hide();  
            $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').slideToggle('slow');
          });

      $('.' + $link.attr("id") + ' > #maincontent').attr("class", $link.attr("id"));

      $link.attr('alt','read less');      
    } else {
      $('#'+ $link.attr("id") + ' > .' + $link.attr("id")).hide();
      $link.attr('alt','read more'); 
    }
    return false;
 });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to help either.  I'm not sure why it isn't just smoothly loading.